# Как можно штатными средствами Nginx принимать файлы POST запроса?

Tags: nginx

Как можно **штатными средствами Nginx** принимать файлы POST запроса? Например есть **100 файлов** отправленных через **JS FormData**, как их возможно принять и сразу записать в конкретную папку с динамическим именем **001.jpg,002.jpg,003.jpg** итд.

Версия nginx: **1.14.0**

Comment: Штатными никак. Есть нештатные модули, например https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/modules/upload/